# How display rows of data in to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to display data from a table which returns 3 (this number may vary) different records for 1 phone number.

Example of result table...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB0db.png

However, what I'd like to do is display it like this, based on the call rank which is ordered by date & time.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIJvZ.png

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of columns you want, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select ani,
       max(case when rank = 1 then calldate end) as calldate_1,
       max(case when rank = 1 then calltime end) as calltime_1,
       max(case when rank = 1 then calltype end) as calltype_1,
       max(case when rank = 2 then calldate end) as calldate_2,
       max(case when rank = 2 then calltime end) as calltime_2,
       max(case when rank = 2 then calltype end) as calltype_2,
       max(case when rank = 3 then calldate end) as calldate_3,
       max(case when rank = 3 then calltime end) as calltime_3,
       max(case when rank = 3 then calltype end) as calltype_3
from t
group by ani;
```

Comment: I had thought of doing that, however the number of calls may vary for each phone numbers in the table. There could be just 2 one day or up to 5/6 the next day so it's not a static figure.

Comment: @SQLNoviceSeekinghelp . . . A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns.  You can repeat the logic up to some reasonable maximum.  Or you could use dynamic SQL.  Or you could restructure the data at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want, but maybe could be useful:

Return two columns (one row for each phone number): ANI and a text column with the rest o data concatenated.

```
SELECT 
        ANI,
        STRING_AGG(
             '[CallDate: ' + CONVERT(varchar, CallDate, 103)  + ', ' 
             'CallTime: ' + CONVERT(varchar, CallTime, 108)  + ', ' 
             'CallTypeID: ' + CAST(CallTypeID AS varchar) + ']', '  ') AS Data
FROM t
GROUP BY ANI;
```

If column type is some text, you don't need to CAST or CONVERT.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with [cursors](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/cursor-in-sql-server/) and [dynamic script](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)
**The solution can be used whatever the number of calls per day is.**

Data are stored in Table **Calls**

Data as you expect are stored in Table **Calls_Columns**

1. first calculate N=the max number of (i) i is the index of calldate,calltime.. columns.

2)Create a table Clls_columns with first column=ANI.

3)then for i=1 to N, add columns calldate_i,calltime_i ...

4)and update each of these columns from CALLS table [using with CTE instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Hope it helps:

```
if exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name='CALLS') drop table calls
if exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name='Calls_column') drop table Calls_column


CREATE TABLE CALLS (ani varchar(20),callDate date,callTime time, calltypeID int,CallRank int)
insert into CALLS values
('01234567890','01/04/2021','12:35:25','111','1'),
('01234567890','01/04/2021','13:35:10','111','2'),
('01234567890','01/04/2021','15:40:00','111','3'),
('71234567890','02/04/2021','12:35:25','112','1'),
('71234567890','02/04/2021','13:35:10','112','2'),
('71234567890','02/04/2021','15:40:00','112','3'),
('71234567890','02/04/2021','17:40:00','112','4')

declare @max as int
set @max=(
select  top 1 count(1) N from CALLS group by calldate order by count(1) desc)

create table Calls_column(ani varchar(20))
declare @script as varchar(max)
declare @i as int

set @i=1
while @i <=@max
begin
set @script='alter table Calls_column  add callDate_'+CAST(@i as varchar(2))+' date'
exec(@script)

set @script='alter table Calls_column  add callTime_'+CAST(@i as varchar(2))+' Time'
exec(@script)

set @script='alter table Calls_column  add calltypeID_'+CAST(@i as varchar(2))+' int'
exec(@script)
set @i=@i+1
end;

 declare mycursor cursor for
with cte as(
select ani,calldate,calltime,calltypeID,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ani order by calltypeid) n from CALLS)
select * from cte
declare @ani as varchar(20)
declare @calldate as date
declare @calltime as time
declare @calltypeID as int
declare @o as int
open mycursor
fetch mycursor into @ani,@calldate,@calltime,@calltypeID,@o
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin

set @script='if not exists(select 1 from Calls_column where ani='''+@ani+''') insert Calls_column(ani)
values('''+@ani+''')'
print @script
exec(@script)

set @script='if exists(select 1 from Calls_column where ani='''+@ani+''') update Calls_column
set calldate_'+CAST(@O AS varchar(2))+'='''+cast(@calldate as varchar(20))+''' where ani='''+@ani+''''
print @script
exec(@script)


set @script='if exists(select 1 from Calls_column where ani='''+@ani+''') update Calls_column
set calltime_'+CAST(@O AS varchar(2))+'='''+cast(@calltime as varchar(20))+''' where ani='''+@ani+''''
print @script
exec(@script)

set @script='if exists(select 1 from Calls_column where ani='''+@ani+''') update Calls_column
set calltypeid_'+CAST(@O AS varchar(2))+'='''+cast(@calltypeid as varchar(20))+''' where ani='''+@ani+''''
print @script
exec(@script)

fetch mycursor into @ani,@calldate,@calltime,@calltypeID,@o
end
close mycursor
deallocate mycursor


select * from Calls_column
```